# Constructing a formule

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Could you help me with that?

\begin{align}
                      1 &= 1 \\
                  1 - 4 &= -(1 + 2) \\
              1 - 4 + 9 &= (1 + 2 + 3) \\
         1 - 4 + 9 - 16 &= -(1 + 2 + 3 + 4) \\
    1 - 4 + 9 - 16 + 25 &= (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5)
\end{align}

Reading above, write a formule for $1^2-2^2+3^2-4^2+\cdots\pm n^2$.

Comment: Yes, for example:   4 is the square of 2 for the second column
, 9 is the square of 3 for 3rd column, and going on

Comment: That's correct. Can you see the relationship between the left hand side of the equations and the thing you need to write a formula for?

Answer (score 2):

$$1^2-2^2+3^2+...=\pm(1+2+3+...)$$
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\cdot k^2 = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n k$$

hint: $$\sum_{k=1}^n k=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$

Comment: Is ... that really ... a hint?

Comment: Well, between this and saying nothing there's not much. But at least it's not a proof.

Comment: thanks, I realise it's not a very good hint but I couldn't really think of what else to say

Comment: That's fair enough. For a question like this, I think part of the problem is the OP hasn't fully understood what the question is asking for - so sometimes the best thing is to try and prompt an answer in the comments - or if you want to write an answer, just to point out some of the patterns.

Comment: Well I think that maybe another solutiopn is:

(-1)^(n+1) * (n(n+1))/2

Answer (score 0):

The direct reason of equality $\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\cdot k^2 = (-1)^{n+1}\sum_{k=1}^n k$ is formula $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$:

$$(n+1)^2-n^2=(n+1+n)(n+1-n)=(2n+1) \cdot 1=(n+1)+n$$

We can prove that by grouping in this way:

(1)for odd $n$: $$1+(-4+9)+(-16+25)+\cdots (-(2n)^2-(2n+1)^2)$$

(2)for even $n$: $$(1-4)+(9-16)+(25-36)+\cdots+((2n-1)^2-(2n)^2)$$